# PowerBI How to compute Dynamic measure based on slicer selection?

Tags: powerbi

Here I like to compute dynamic measure called "count_percent" (last field) based on slicer selection.

1. Formula for 'count_percent' is ...Admin/count
2. Slicers in PowerBI = Diag and Practice
3. Bar chart has Date on X column (1/1/2018 to 1/3/2018) and 'count_percent' on Y column

In this example,

- if I select Diag slicer = Head and Practice = open or select all, I
  like to see 'count_percent' for 1/1/2018, itshould be 6 (24/4)
- if I select Diag slicer = Head and Practice slicer = Practice 1, i
  like to see 'count_percent for    1/1/2018, it should be 5 (10/2)
- if I select Diag = open and practice = 1, i like to see 'count_percent' for 1/1/2018 is 4.16 (25/6)

Please hlep. My data sample is below. Thank you so much

```
Date    Diag    Practice    Admin   count   count_percent
01/01/2018  Head    Practice1   10  2   
01/02/2018  Head    Practice1   22  3   
01/03/2018  Head    Practice1   13  3   
01/01/2018  Head    Practice2   14  2   
01/02/2018  Head    Practice2   13  2   
01/01/2018  Neck    Practice1   15  4   
01/02/2018  Neck    Practice1   17  2   
01/03/2018  Neck    Practice1   12  2   
01/01/2018  Neck    Practice2   18  3   
01/02/2018  Neck    Practice2   20  4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be as simple as this: `count_percent = DIVIDE(SUM(admin), SUM(count))`

Comment: Thank you. I am new to PowerBI and your answer did help encourage me to learn more. :-)